# rendering and binding form with checkbox data

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

How can we create checkboxes and bind them with our form in play2.0 using scala.

If I have

```
    val placeForm = Form(
    mapping(
        "id" -> ignored(NotAssigned: Pk[Long]),
        "url_key" -> nonEmptyText,
        "title" -> optional(text),
        "page_id" -> optional(longNumber)
    )(models.Place.apply)(models.Place.unapply)
)
```

and I have created form like this.

```
    @form(routes.Page.save) {

    @form(routes.Page.save) {

    <fieldset>

    @inputText(pageForm("title"), '_label -> "Title")
    @inputText(pageForm("template"), '_label -> "Template") <label>Options:</label>
    <div class="input">
        <label>note <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="0">
        </label> <label>About US <input type="checkbox" name="options[]"
        value="0">
        </label> <label>Facebook <input type="checkbox" name="options[]"
        value="0">
        </label> <label>Twitter <input type="checkbox" name="options[]"
        value="0">
        </label> <label>Hotmail <input type="checkbox" name="options[]"
        value="0">
        </label> <label>Something <input type="checkbox" name="options[]"
        value="0">
        </label>
    </div>


    </fieldset>
```

Now I want dont want simple html to create these checkboxes and bind these checkbox values into form

Can anyone help me with this

Comment: see play documentation on forms, use @checkbox(...) to generate these elements

Answer (score 1):

The structure of your `val placeForm` must match the form that you render in your template.

For example :

```
val placeForm = Form(
    mapping(
        "id" -> ignored(NotAssigned: Pk[Long]),
        "title" -> optional(text),
        "template" -> optional(text),
        "checkbox1" -> text
        "checkbox2" -> text
    ) // ... here construction and deconstruction functions
)
```

Your template can lookes like :

```
@form(routes.Page.save) {

    <fieldset>

    @inputText(pageForm("title"), '_label -> "Title")
    @inputText(pageForm("template"), '_label -> "Template") 

<label>Options:</label>

<div class="input">
        <label> 1 <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="1"> </label>
        <label> 2 <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" value="2"> </label>
    </div>

    </fieldset>
}
```

Now it's important to understand for wich purposes are these checkboxes. If you want to bind there values to your `case class Place` and your form structure match completely your case class, you can use apply and unaplly method, if no ... you must utilise your custom functions...

```
((title, template, checkbox1, checkbox2)=> Place(title, template, checkbox1, checkbox2))  //construct function

((place : Place) => Some((place.title, place.template, place.property_that_correspond_to_checkbox1_value,place.property_that_correspond_to_checkbox2_value)) // deconstruct function
```

Or you can  use `tuple` instead of `mapping` for a form construction and then get your values simply as tuple values

Comment: Thank you Arussinov, but what if I want to implement some logic as per the no of checked check boxes, and then stored the calculated result in a simple column named options. Is it possible??

Comment: Why not, you can construct your form in this way: `val placeForm = Form(
    mapping(
        "id" -> ignored(NotAssigned: Pk[Long]),
        "title" -> optional(text),
        "template" -> optional(text),
        "checkbox1" -> boolean
        "checkbox2" -> boolean
    ) // ... here construction and deconstruction functions
)` and use these boolean values in your logic (your custom functions) also there is method `checked` in play.api.data.Forms ...`"checkbox2" -> checked("Your text here")...`